# Adding macOS Document Type Icon

Tags: xcode, macos, info.plist

I'm making a document based macOS app. What I'm trying to do is add the document icon. I've done this before several years ago with Objective-C, but I'm having issues getting it to work on my Swift app. This is what I got under the Info section:

[image]

My icon is called JotSpot Doc.png and is placed in the root level of the project along with all of the Swift and Storyboard files (not in the assets folder).
Here is what my info.plist looks like:

[image]

When submitting to Apple I got a warning that said

> The CFBundleDocumentTypes dictionary array in the
>   'com.website.app' Info.plist should contain an
>   LSHandlerRank value for the CFBundleTypeName 'png' entry.

When saving a document using the app, it's completely blank and there is no icon at all (not even a blank white icon). You actually have to click on the document name to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type to image/png. And then add the handler rank.

Here is the code from my section (for opening GPX files).

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Open Fit File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Open Gpx File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.dt.document.gpx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```